# I have two distinct git repos. How to replace one with newer?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have my live site on my web server and locally on my development machine.  It is one of my git repositories on bitbucket.

Using Laravel, they suggested to upgrade to their newest version the recommended way is to create a completely new project, migrate in your old files, test, then deploy.  I did that yesterday so now I have two versions of my site with two different git repos on bitbucket.

1. What is the preferred way in this situation of keeping a backup of the old site and deploying the new site on my web server?
2. In bitbucket, I have mysite.com and "mysite on laravel5" repos.  Ideally, once I have archived the mysite.com (old version), I'd like my new one to just be called mysite.com.  How could I do that?

Comment: you could have just branched your repository, upgrade and if succesful merge the branch

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are more ways how to do this, for ex. - you should clone new git repository to another directory on webserver (webnew) and then rename original directory with older version (web) to other name (webold) and replace original with new directory (webnew -> web) - if something goes wrong, you can return back original directory.
2. In Bitbucket open repo and choose Settings / Repository detail and change Name

If you change name of repo, URL address will change too, so you need to change remote path in git repo.